# How to use daterangeinput in r Shiny to filter by columns that have months and years by name?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, shiny, stringr

I have a list of people and the number of projects that they are working on each month. I want users of my shiny app to select the months displayed by the date range input.

```
library(dplyr)
    testdata <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley"),
                       apr_2021 = c(10, 100, 101),
                       may_2021 = c(1, 4, 7),
                       jun_2021 = c(4, 5, 6),
                       jul_2021 = c(11, 11, 45),
                       aug_2021 = c(4, 5, 7),
                       sep_2021 = c(2, 1, 0),
                       oct_2021 = c(4, 5, 8),
                       nov_2021 = c(4, 1, 1))
```

I configured my daterangeinput() to be in the format of M-YYYY, or Oct_2021. When I try to adjust the date_filter input, I get an error that the column doesn't exist (for instance, when users put in August 3rd 2021:

```
Warning: Error in : Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `2021_03` doesn't exist.
```

There's one of two solutions. Ideally, I'd like to know why R is changing the format I specified in the daterangeinput and how to fix it, so I can keep my current code (below). I'm not sure if it has to do with me using the today() function, but I need R to pick up on the current month and year.

A secondary solution if that's not possible is how do I get these strings into the new format that R is trying to use (which seems to be YYYY-mm-dd).

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)


ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("View 1", fluid = TRUE,
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         h4("Select Your Desired Filters"),
                         div(id = "inputs",
                             dateRangeInput(
                                 inputId = "date_filter",
                                 label = "Filter by Month and Year",
                                 start = today(),
                                 end = (today() + 90),
                                 min = "Apr-2021",
                                 max = NULL,
                                 format = "M-yyyy",
                                 startview = "month",
                                 weekstart = 0,
                                 language = "en",
                                 separator = " to ",
                                 width = NULL,
                                 autoclose = TRUE
                             ),
                             br()),
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
                         
                     )
                 )
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    #Here's the dataset
    testdata <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley"),
                       apr_2021 = c(10, 100, 101),
                       may_2021 = c(1, 4, 7),
                       jun_2021 = c(4, 5, 6),
                       jul_2021 = c(11, 11, 45),
                       aug_2021 = c(4, 5, 7),
                       sep_2021 = c(2, 1, 0),
                       oct_2021 = c(4, 5, 8),
                       nov_2021 = c(4, 1, 1))
    
    select_values <- reactive({

        from_date <- as.character(input$date_filter[1])
        
        from_date <- tolower(str_replace_all(from_date, "-..-", "_"))
        
        
        to_date <- as.character(input$date_filter[2])
        
        to_date <- tolower(str_replace_all(to_date, "-..-", "_"))
        
        testdata %>%
            dplyr::select(employee, from_date:to_date)
    })

    
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(select_values())
    })
    
    

    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the tightest code, but I got it to work.

Rather than treating each date as a string initially, I made them into a simple 1x1 tibble, so I could use case_when(), separate(), and then unite() the strings in the proper order.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(dplyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)


ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("View 1", fluid = TRUE,
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         h4("Select Your Desired Filters"),
                         div(id = "inputs",
                             dateRangeInput(
                                 inputId = "date_filter",
                                 label = "Filter by Month and Year",
                                 start = today(),
                                 end = (today() + 90),
                                 min = "Apr-2021",
                                 max = NULL,
                                 format = "M-yyyy",
                                 startview = "month",
                                 weekstart = 0,
                                 language = "en",
                                 separator = " to ",
                                 width = NULL,
                                 autoclose = TRUE
                             ),
                             br()),
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
                         
                     )
                 )
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    #Here's the dataset
    testdata <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley"),
                       apr_2021 = c(10, 100, 101),
                       may_2021 = c(1, 4, 7),
                       jun_2021 = c(4, 5, 6),
                       jul_2021 = c(11, 11, 45),
                       aug_2021 = c(4, 5, 7),
                       sep_2021 = c(2, 1, 0),
                       oct_2021 = c(4, 5, 8),
                       nov_2021 = c(4, 1, 1))
    
    select_values <- reactive({

        from_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1]))
        
        
        from_date <- from_date %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
        
        from_date <- parse_character(from_date$month_year)
        
        
        
        to_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[2]))
        
        to_date <- to_date %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")  
        
        to_date <- parse_character(to_date$month_year)
        
        testdata %>%
            dplyr::select(employee, from_date:to_date)
    })

    
    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(select_values())
    })
    
    

    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```